# Installation of Laravel - Vue SPA on apache web server

Tags: laravel, apache, vue.js, single-page-application

I have three apps, one backend for api, second for frontend admin and third for frontend user.
I use Laravel and Vue.

Api is located on `/var/www/app/backend`

User app is located in `/var/www/app/frontend`

Admin app is located in `/var/www/api/frontend-admin`

Here is example of my virtual host config

```
                RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/backend/public/$1 -f
                RewriteRule  ^/api/(.*)$ /backend/public/$1  [L,QSA]
                
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /backend/public/index.php/$1 [L]

                RewriteRule ^/admin/(.*$) /frontend-admin/dist/$1 [L,QSA]

                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/dist/$1 [L]
```

Api and users app works correctly, but problem is admin app.
If I access from browser to `/admin` apache redirect me to admin app, but if I access `/admin/something` apache redirect me to user app...